# Define decorator parameter outside of module scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following decorator running fine using a parameter

```
from functools import wraps

def sumproduct(cnt):
    def dec(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args):
            print('inside wrapper')
            _sum = 0
            for i in range(cnt):
                _sum = _sum + sum([i * a for a in args])
            f(_sum)
        return wrap
    return dec

cnt = 3
@sumproduct(cnt)
def myfunc(num):
    print(num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunc(10)
```

The output is `30` which is `0*10 + 1*10+ 2*10`

However, I would like to import this module somewhere else, for example into a test module. I would like to do something like the following so that `cnt` is not defined in global scope:

```
from functools import wraps

def sumproduct(cnt):
    def dec(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args):
            print('inside wrapper')
            _sum = 0
            for i in range(cnt):
                _sum = _sum + sum([i * a for a in args])
            f(_sum)
        return wrap
    return dec

@sumproduct(cnt)
def myfunc(num):
    print(num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cnt = 3
    myfunc(10)
```

How can I define `cnt` so that

1. `cnt` is always 3 when code is executed?
2. and `cnt` is not imported when module is imported?

**Note:** This is just a sample representation of the code. Suppose that `cnt` is database connection which connects to production database. I would like to use a different database connection for tests, hence I don't want to import production database connection into test module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `@sumproduct(lambda: cnt)`. That way the execution is delayed.

For example:

```
from functools import wraps

def sumproduct(cnt):
    def dec(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args):
            print('inside wrapper')
            _sum = 0
            for i in range(cnt()):  # <---- Note the ()
                _sum = _sum + sum([i * a for a in args])
            f(_sum)
        return wrap
    return dec


@sumproduct(lambda: cnt) # <--- put lambda: here
def myfunc(num):
    print(num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cnt = 3
    myfunc(10)
```

Prints:

```
inside wrapper
30
```

Comment: Thanks ,this definitely answers the first question. Regarding the second one, when I want to import the module as follows: `from my_module import * \n cnt = 4 \n myfunc(10)`, I receive `NameError: name 'cnt' is not defined`. How can I define `cnt` as part of `my_module`?

Comment: @Tehscript One solution might be to put `cnt` in separate module, that is imported from inside `my_module`. Better will be put there a function `get_cnt()` that returns `cnt` based on some configuration (test. production,...)

Comment: It was a good point. I tried that but it didn't work because I still have to define `cnt = get_cnt` after I import it. (I need to configure get_cnt for each environtment). It is exactly the same thing as `cnt = 3`. Am I missing your point?

Comment: @Tehscript you can have `cnt = get_cnt()`. Inside the `get_cnt()` the function checks, for example, environment variable - and when this variable is set to `PRODUCTION` or nothing, returns real connection, and when is set to `TEST` return test connection.

Comment: I can actually import the connection module either from its own module or from this module. They will both work. After playing around with the import, I came up with this solution and it seems to be working `import my_module \n my_module.cnt = 4 \n my_module.myfunc(10)`. Output is `60` Thanks for your time.